# Windows disable screen share and programmatic input

Tags: windows, security, screen

For security reasons

1. I want to disable screen shot or screen sharing by any known/unknown program.
2. I also want to disable any programmatic mouse and keyboard or any other input. While physical keyboard/mouse should work.
3. **Only person sitting in front of the computer should be able to access physical machine without any issue.**

This is for security reason. No body should be able to put malware/spyware and see what i am doing.

Answer (score 1):

- `SetwindowDisplayAffinity` to disable screen shot of a window.
- Use a [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to detect and ignore injected keystrokes.